# Selenium Python Bot WhatsApp

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Estoy haciendo un bot de envio de mensajes de para WhatsApp en Selenium con Python 3.9v, resulta que es bastante sencillo pero en la linea donde envia el send_keys del mensaje no lo hace y se la saltea, luego me dice que no encuentra la clase '_4sWnG'. Soy nueva en esto, necesitaria una ayuda para que pueda enviar el mensaje que yo le pongo en el input.  Aqui dejo mi codigo con la lineas comentadas explicando mejor lo que sucede.

```
driver.get("https://web.whatsapp.com/")

name = input('enter the name of user:')
msg = input('enter your message:')
input('enter anything after scanning QR code')

user = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@title = "{}"]'.format(name))
user.click()

msg_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
        '/html/body/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[4]/div[1]/footer/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]') #/html/body/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[4]/div[1]/footer/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]
time.sleep(3)

msg_box.send_keys(msg) #No hace esta linea
time.sleep(10) #Espera 10 segundos
button = driver.find_element_by_class_name('_4sWnG') #Dice que no lo encuentra porque efectivamente no puso ningun mensaje
button.click()
print("Mensaje enviado!")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que seleccionaste la xpath que no era.
identifica el div que tiene el texto --Escribe un mensaje aqui--, debajo de ese, hay otro div, ese div es al que le vas a sacar la xpath.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

xpath de esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

prueba con esta

```py
# xpath: //*[@id="main"]/footer/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]
```

Comment: por favor considera agregar un ejemplo, así todo se entenderá mejor :)

Comment: @Christian listo, gracias por la sugerencia.

Comment: ok, pero como sería el código?

Comment: @Christian pues a veces puede variar dependiendo, ya le indiqué que es lo que tiene que hacer, pero no pierde nada intentando con esta xpath: (//*[@id="main"]/footer/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[2])

Comment: eso es lo que debería ir en tu respuesta, recomiendo que leas [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @Christian vale, la próxima vez seré mas especifico y detallado :)

Comment: Muchas gracias! Me funciono perfecto. Era ese el problema ‍♀️‍♀️